# Take <p> as an integer

Tags: javascript

```
<button onclick="nums()">Input</button>
<p id="number">5</p>
<p id="aNumber"></p>

<script>
function nums() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
  var y = parseInt(1);
  var z = x + y;
  document.getElementById("aNumber").innerHTML = z;
}
</script>

</body>
```

I can't understand why this does not work.  What do I need to do to get p with id number to go into a function and turn into an int?

Comment: p element does not have a value.

Comment: It has a value of 5?

Comment: No it has text/html of 5. There is no value, it is not an input.

Answer (score 3):

An element has a value if it's in input element or something like that, here, you have the content of your p tag.

This will work:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("number").innerText);
```

Btw, you don't need the parseInt to define y:

```
var y = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
document.getElementById("number").innerText
```

`value` is only for input elements, not for normal HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

or use textContent, but it's will return string

```js
function nums() {
  var x = document.getElementById("number").textContent;
  x = parseInt(Number(x))
  var y = 1;
  var z = x + y;
  document.getElementById("aNumber").innerHTML = z;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="nums()">Input</button>
<p id="number">5</p>
<p id="aNumber"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text within the `<p>` tag, is not retrieved by `.value`.

You should retrieve with something like the following:

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").innerText);
```